# Why php to mySQL data import look like this?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm importing data from variables in php (from read csv) and send it to a MySQL table. But they appear this:

The data has like spaces in it, but if we want to edit the content... go to image 2

IMAGE 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PvFE.png

It says that have only one character!!

IMAGE 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/crjE3.png

I test that if you print the variables before import it all data are good, without any spaces.

This is my query in php:

```
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO $name(keyword, adGroup, currency, busquedasMes, competencia, puja) VALUES('$adgroup','$adgroup','$currency','$busquedasMes','$competencia','$puja')");
```

**EDIT**:

This is my import.php code, the CSV is delimited by tabs, so I need to change it to ";"

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass')
    or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']["name"];


$trozos = explode("." , $nombre);
$cuantos = count($trozos);
$nombreLimpio = $trozos[$cuantos - 2];


mysql_select_db('prueba1') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $nombreLimpio (keyword VARCHAR(30), adGroup VARCHAR(30), currency VARCHAR(30), busquedasMes VARCHAR(30), competencia VARCHAR(30), puja VARCHAR(30))");


$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$archivotmp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];


$lineas = file($archivotmp);

$i=0;

foreach ($lineas as $linea_num => $linea)
{ 

   if($i != 0) 
   { 

 $lala = str_replace('/\t/', ';', $linea);
 $datos = explode(";",$lala);

       $adgroup = trim($datos[0]);
      $keyword = trim($datos[1]);
       $currency = trim($datos[2]);
       $busquedasMes = trim($datos[3]);
       $competencia = str_replace('"', "", trim($datos[4]));
       echo $keyword;
       $puja = str_replace(' ', "",$competencia);


       mysql_query("INSERT INTO $nombreLimpio(keyword, adGroup, currency, busquedasMes, competencia, puja) VALUES('$keyword','$adgroup','$currency','$busquedasMes','$competencia','$puja')");

   }


   $i++;
}


mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Example of my CSV file:

```
Seed Keywords   android EUR 2740000 "0,12"  "0,61"              Y   N
```

Comment: It looks like you're just missing a font, so the text is displaying strangely. (There aren't really spaces.) As an aside, please stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They were deprecated in PHP 5.5, which is so old that it no longer even receives security updates, and completely removed in PHP 7. Instead, use PDO or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: Yes I would suspect that the error is in the Database GUI. Try another Database tool and look at the data.

Comment: mysql_query() AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!